# PrologBeans - the format in which lists are returned

Tags: prolog

I've got this in a Prolog file:

```
:- module(test,[main/0, api_trial/2]
:- use_module(library(prologbeans)).

main:-
  register_query(assert_trial(Age,Res), api_trial(Age,Res)),
  start.

person('John',10,'London').
person('Adam',10,'Manchester').

api_trial(Age,Res) :-
    findall((P,Age,Add),person(P,Age,Add),Res).
```

In Java, I do the following query (after importing the correct classes etc):

```
  public void trial() {
    try{
      Bindings bindings = new Bindings().bind("Age",10);
      QueryAnswer answer = session.executeQuery("assert_trial(Age,Res)", bindings);
      Term result = answer.getValue("Res");
      System.out.println("Answer returned " + result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalCharacterSetException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Basically, my problem is that the format it returns the query in Java.
In Prolog, it's normal:

```
Res = [('John',10,'London'),('Adam',10,'Manchester')] ?
```

In Java, I get:

```
Answer returned [,(John,,(10,London)),,(Adam,,(10,Manchester))]
```

The formatting is messed up. How can I overcome this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Prolog implementation are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use toString() to created the Java output? Most likely the toString()
implements a write the is inbetween write_canonical and write.

From write_canonical it would share that operators f are not respected. Instead
they are normally written as f(a1,a2) respectively f(a1).

One operator definition that every prolog has is the comma, that is why we can 
input (A,B), but write_canonical will write it as ','(A,B):

```
  ?- X = (A,B), write_canonical(X).
  ','(_,_)
  X = (A,B)
```

What I now see in your output is, that it has also been stripped by the quotes.
This is the normal behaviour of write:

```
  ?- X = 'hello world!', write(X).
  hello world!
  X = 'hello world!'
```

The write operation that would both respect operators and put quotes where necessary
would be writeq.

Best Regards